# How to implement the sliding menu and swipe to dismiss listview together

Tags: android, listview, slidingmenu

I am having a listview with sliding menu (from:https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), so the menu appear when user swipe from left to right. And now I would like to have another gesture control feature which is swipe a list item from right to left to dismiss an item. Is it possible and how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend to not use https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview because it is incredibly bugged.

Answer (score 0):

Try [android-swipetodismiss](https://github.com/romannurik/android-swipetodismiss) library.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation that I have found most impressive is Tim Roe's [EnhancedListView](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/23/enhancedlistview-swipe-to-dismiss-with-undo/)